# Setting user rights assignment of local security policy using powershell/cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to edit security settings of user rights assignment of local security policy using powershell or cmd.

```
Eg: policy =  "change the system time"
default_security_settings = "local service,Administrators"
i want to remove everything except Administrators
```

i have tried ntrights command, but seems like not working
Any command will be appreciated

Comment: What exactly did you try and where did it fail? Please provide us with your code so that we can help you work out the kinks, not write the code for you.

Comment: i have tried "cmd ntrights +r SeSystemtimePrivilege -u Administrators" @Nick

Comment: wherea in cmd it shows ntright command does not exist

Comment: ...that means you don't have 'ntrights.exe' that exists somewhere in your $PATH statement.  Considering it's a tool from the W2K3 resource kit, you probably don't have it downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something i just wrote. You can make it more dynamic

```
function Replace-SecurityTest([string[]]$Usernames,[string]$SecuritySetting, $SaveFile = "C:\Configuration.cfg"){
    function Get-SID($USER){
        $objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount("$USER")
        $strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
        $strSID.Value
    }
    secedit /export /cfg $SaveFile
    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($SaveFile)
    while($null -ne ($line = $reader.ReadLine())) {
        if ($Line -like "*$SecuritySetting*"){
            $reader.Close()
            $line2 = $line.Remove($line.IndexOf("="))
            $line2 += "= "
            foreach($user in $Usernames){
                $line2 += "*$(Get-SID -USER "$user"), "
            }
            $line2 = $line2.Remove($line2.LastIndexOf(", "))
            (gc $SaveFile).replace("$Line", "$Line2") | Out-File $SaveFile
            secedit /configure /db c:\windows\security\local.sdb /cfg $SaveFile /areas SECURITYPOLICY
            rm -force $SaveFile -confirm:$false
            break
        }
    }

}

Replace-SecurityTest -Usernames "Administrators" -SecuritySetting "SeSystemtimePrivilege" -SaveFile "C:\Config22.cfg"
```

Comment: thanks for help, but my job solved [ https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Grant-Revoke-Query-user-26e259b0#content ]

Answer (score 1):

```
$account = "accountName"
$userRight = "SeServiceLogonRight*"

$code = (Start-Process secedit -ArgumentList "/export /areas USER_RIGHTS /cfg c:\policies.inf" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
if ($code -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Output "security template exported successfully exit code $code"
    }
else
    {
        Write-Output "security template export failed exit code $code"
    }

$sid = ((Get-LocalUser $account).SID).Value

$policy = Get-Content C:\policies.inf
$newpol = @()
foreach ($line in $policy)
    {
        if ($line -like $userRight)
            {
                $line = $line + ",*$sid"
            }

        $newpol += $line
    }

$newpol | Out-File C:\policies.inf -Force

$code = (Start-Process secedit -ArgumentList "/configure /db secedit.sdb /cfg C:\policies.inf /areas USER_RIGHTS /log C:\policies.log" -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
if ($code -eq 0)
    {
        Write-Output "exit code $code"
    }
else
    {
        Write-Output "exit code $code"
    }

Remove-Item -Path c:\policies.inf -Force
```

Comment: Some explanation in addition to code would assist users understanding the value of your answer. Code only answers are often consider impolite and unhelpful for learners. Please use the [edit] button to enhance your answer.